# how to fix port for client application

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, client, console-application

I am developing console application in visual studio(c#). I need to continuously listen from server's defined IP & port. On listening to from that IP & port I will get data of call logs from [epabx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_telephone_system#Private_branch_exchange). Problem is I am developing client socket will communicate through any free port selected by OS. PBX only allows to communicate through pre-configured port number. I don't find any answer about how to configure port for client in advance so that application communicates from that port only. Any help will be good.

Many showed to change port for web application but i want to configure port for console application.
Here is my code sample if it helps in any way:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClientSocket
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient();
            clientSocket.Connect(destinationPort, destinationPort);
            //((System.Net.IPEndPoint)(clientSocket.Client.LocalEndPoint)).Port = 3389; I want to fix my port in advance something like this or any other way
            Console.WriteLine(" >> Client Started");

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                    byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("" + "$");
                    Console.WriteLine("\nPing to Server:");
                    serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
                    serverStream.Flush();

                    byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
                    serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
                    string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
                    Console.WriteLine("Reply from server:" + returndata);
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you commented line will be enough to set local end point port number.

```
IPEndPoint ipLocalEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(localIPAddress, clientPort);
TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient(ipLocalEndPoint);
clientSocket.Connect(serverIP, serverPort);
```

Comment: I have pbx model - "Matrix Eternity NE"
On debugging, First time it shows answer like  
>>Client started:  
Ping to server:  
Reply from server: ???????  
some question marks and smiley  
After 5 second  
Ping to server:  
Reply from server:  
Eternity Login:$  
Any help with this! Thanks.

Comment: As per your program it just prints the data whatever received from the server. You need to check the server protocol that whether the server program has written to send some acknowledgement kind of thing...

Comment: and also make sure while printing the read data, you are printing entire array. Instead try to convert only the number of bytes received(i.e use  serverStream.Read() function return value to get the number of bytes read from the server.).

Comment: Helpful answer. Initially, I thought it is client side programming but later I found that i need to write server and will recieve data on my side. And yes I should not print whole array. And yes now I am trimming  serverStream.Read() to get rid off null values in the end

Comment: happy to hear that u sorted out.